# Where is the source code of libc6-dev-i386 from?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, glibc

I see this. Where the source of libc6-dev-i386 is from?

```
$ apt-file search /usr/include/sys/socket.h
libc6-dev-i386: /usr/include/sys/socket.h
```

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libc6

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html

Is it from git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git?

Comment: See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libc6-dev-i386 .

Comment: It's unclear if you seek that source code for a specific release of Ubuntu, or the upstream (https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html) or something else. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Why list the packages.debian.org?  Are you using Debian and not Ubuntu?  This site is for Ubuntu and flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic    You should also provide a release, and I've seen two packages change source in the last ~month (so an answer for *hirsute* is different to other releases.. this happens so release matters)

Answer (score 1):

It tells you on the page for the package on the right hand side. It gives the origin as the GNU.org, with links to the files needed to build it linked there as well. The .orig.tar.xz is the original source package from the GNU the other two the Debian files used to build the packages with the changes made. This is the same for all packages, lookup their pages and you get the same information.

https://packages.debian.org/sid/libc6